# How to call mapStateToProps method from a mixin in Polymer3-Redux

Tags: javascript, redux, polymer-3.x

I am using this polymer-redux repo from github in my examples:

> https://github.com/tur-nr/polymer-redux/tree/dev/v2.x

I have the redux-todo component which connects the todoApp with the redux store. I also created a mixin from where I would like to inherit some properties and at the same time I would like to connect one of this property to the store from the mixin. I manage to call the mapStateToProps method from the mixin but unfortunately it never bind the property to the store.

Here is what I have so far:

**redux-todo.js:**

```
import TodoApp from 'todo-app';
import ReduxMixin from 'mixins/redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'polymer-redux';
import { AnotherMixin } from 'another-mixin.js';
import { ExtraMixin } from 'extra-mixin.js';

class ReduxTodo extends AnotherMixin(ExtraMixin(ReduxMixin(TodoApp))) {
    /**
     * We map any redux state to the element properties here. Feel free to use
     * libraries like reselect to improve the performance of your app.
     *
     * @param {object} state The redux state object.
     * @param {HTMLElement} element The element instance.
     *
     * @return {Object} Key-value map of properties and their values.
     */


    static mapStateToProps(state, element) {
        super.mapStateToProps(state);
        console.log('mapping props');
        console.dir(state);
        console.dir(this);
        return {
            tasks: state.tasks,
            extras: state.extras,//from extras mixin
            //another: state.another
        };
    }

    constructor(){
        super();
        console.log(this.extras);
        console.log(this.another);
    }

    ready() {
        super.ready();
        // do something that requires access to the shadow tree
        console.log(this.extras);
        console.log(this.another);
        console.log(this.tasks);
        //console.log(this.mapStateToProps);
        ;
      }


    /**
     * Mapping dispatch to CustomEvents that bubble from internal elements.
     * This is only called once so make sure you bind correctly.
     *
     * Use the exported helper `bindActionCreators` to construct a key-value map
     * of events that will call `dispatch` with the returning value.
     *
     * @param {Function} dispatch The redux dispatch function.
     * @param {HTMLElement} element The element instance.
     *
     * @return {Object} Key-value map of event names and their listeners.
     */
    static mapDispatchToEvents(dispatch, element) {
        return bindActionCreators(
            {
                addTask(event) {
                    return {
                        type: 'ADD_TASK',
                        task: event.detail
                    };
                },
                updateTaskDone(event) {
                    return {
                        type: 'UPDATE_TASK_DONE',
                        index: event.detail.index,
                        done: event.detail.done
                    };
                },
                removeTask(event) {
                    return {
                        type: 'REMOVE_TASK',
                        index: event.detail
                    };
                }
            },
            dispatch
        );
    }
}

customElements.define('redux-todo', ReduxTodo);
```

**another-mixin.js:**

```
import {dedupingMixin} from '@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/mixin.js';
import ReduxMixin from 'mixins/redux';

let internalAnotherMixin = (base) =>
  class extends ReduxMixin(base) {
    static get properties() {
        return {
            another:{
                type:Boolean,
                value: true
            } 
        };
    }
    constructor(){
        super();
        console.log("Hello from another constructor");
        //this.another = true;
    }

    static mapStateToProps(state, element) {
        console.log('mapping props from another-mixin');
        console.dir(this);
        console.dir(state);
        return {
            another: state.another
        };
    }

  }

  export const AnotherMixin = dedupingMixin(internalAnotherMixin);
```

**extra-mixin.js:**

```
import {dedupingMixin} from '@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/mixin.js';

let internalExtraMixin = (base) =>
  class extends base {
    static get properties() {
        return {
            extras: String
        };
    }
    constructor(){
        super();
        console.log("Hello from extras constructor");
        //this.extras = "Hello world";
    }
  }

  export const ExtraMixin = dedupingMixin(internalExtraMixin);
```

If I call the mapStateToProps method from the redux-todo.js it works as it should but if I want to use the mixin in different classes I have to do it in all of them, so I was just wondering if it is possible to call it from the mixin.

In the store the value for the another property is false. After running my code and logging the props it is still true so it is not working....

### **Edit 1:**

Also I just noticed that every action is getting called twice. So when I am adding something to the todo list the element is added to the list 2 times
I fixed this issue by removing the ReduxMixin from the redux-todo.js. Since I am adding it to another-mixin.js the redux-todo.js will inherit it.

**This is the new redux.todo.js:**

```
...
class ReduxTodo extends AnotherMixin(ExtraMixin((TodoApp))) {
...
}
```

### **Edit 2:**

For this duplicate import problem it is also a good solution in this case if I just remove the ReduxMixin from the mixins and just leave it in the redux-todo.js(it is inherited from there so it will work in the mixins as well)

Comment: in ```Redux``` you can use ```connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent)```

Comment: Hello my comment might be stupid but as far as I know it is only available in react-redux and I am not using that library.